# Python module to create music playlist (windows)

Tags: python, windows

I want to create a simple python script that look into folders and subfolders and create a playlist with the name of the folder containing the mp3's. But so far I have only came across python modules that work on linux OR I could not figure out howto install them (pymad)..

It's just for my android mobile so figured that the m3u format should do it.. I don't care for any other meta data than the name of the mp3 files themself.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/fappy/ perhaps? (But then - how does `(windows)` relate to an android device)?

Comment: What is the problem with `os.walk` and `os.path.splitext` ?

Comment: @mmgp no problem at all - it's actually a good idea! I just didn't know of os.walk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually just looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U and saw that it is quite easy to write m3u files... should be able to do it with simple python write to text file`

Here is my solution

```
import os
import glob

dir = os.getcwd()

for (path, subdirs, files) in os.walk(dir):
    os.chdir(path)
    if glob.glob("*.mp3") != []:
        _m3u = open( os.path.split(path)[1] + ".m3u" , "w" )
        for song in glob.glob("*.mp3"):
            _m3u.write(song + "\n")
        _m3u.close()

os.chdir(dir) # Not really needed..
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up some code which will return a list of all nested playlist candidates based on your criteria:

```
import os

#Input: A path to a folder
#Output: List containing paths to all of the nested folders of path
def getNestedFolderList(path):

    rv = [path]
    ls = os.listdir(path)
    if not ls:
        return rv

    for item in ls:
        itemPath = os.path.join(path,item)
        if os.path.isdir(itemPath):
            rv= rv+getNestedFolderList(itemPath)

    return rv

#Input:  A path to a folder
#Output: (folderName,path,mp3s) if the folder contains mp3s. Else None
def getFolderPlaylist(path):
    mp3s = []
    ls = os.listdir(path)
    for item in ls:
        if item.count('mp3'):
            mp3s.append(item)

    if len(mp3s) > 0:
        folderName = os.path.basename(path)
        return (folderName,path,mp3s)
    else:
        return None

#Input:  A path to a folder
#Output: List of all candidate playlists
def getFolderPlaylists(path):
    rv = []
    nestedFolderList = getNestedFolderList(path)
    for folderPath in nestedFolderList:
        folderPlaylist = getFolderPlaylist(folderPath)
        if folderPlaylist:
            rv.append(folderPlaylist)

    return rv

print getFolderPlaylists('.')
```

Comment: You should be using `os.walk`. Also, is `gimp3.png` a mp3 file ? `x.count` is really wrong here, use `os.path.splitext` and possibly combine it with basic file identification.

Comment: Thank you but I have already solved the problem (see my post). But thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Ahh yes, forgot about os.walk.  And you are correct, count is a sloppier way to do it.  Thanks for the feedback!