# Use datestring in a filename to create folder directory and move files

Tags: regex, shell, date

The script I'm trying to pull of should move files to a destination folder and place them in "year/month/" folders according to the files name which starts with YYYY-MM-DD.

Example:

```
2013-08-03-image_name.png -> ~/B/uploads/2013/08/2013-08-03-image_name.png
2012-01-01-image_name.png -> ~/B/uploads/2012/01/2012-01-01-image_name.png
```

### Plan of action

**(1)** Set path variables

```
source=~/Desktop/A/
targetPath=~/Desktop/B/uploads/
```

**(2)** Perform these actions on each file in `$source`

```
cd "$source";
for i in *.png
do
    # STEP 3
    # STEP 4
done
```

**(3)** Step 3: Image Optimization √

**(4)** Step 4: File away files to directory that machtes datename

**(4a)** Search for datestring in filename via  `^(\d{4})-(\d{2})` and create `$datePath`, c.f. `datePath=2013/08/`. I image this something like this…

```
awk -F … somehow put the regex here with a search and replace "-" into "/"
and save it as a variable.
```

**(4b)** Create new target directory if it doesn't exist and move files there.

```
targetDir=$targetPath$datePath
mkdir -p $targetDir
mv -v "$i" "$destination"
```

PS: Bash would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am providing you solution for finding target path for your files in pure BASH:

```
f='2013-08-03-image_name.png'
targetPath=~/Desktop/B/uploads/
[[ "$f" =~ ^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2}) ]] && \
           echo "$targetPath${BASH_REMATCH[1]}/${BASH_REMATCH[2]}/$f"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
~/Desktop/B/uploads/2013/08/2013-08-03-image_name.png
```

Comment: Short and sweet. This worked splendid. I'll do some research on the BASH_REMATCH trick. Could definitely come in handy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `find` + `egrep` to filter, then `sed` to build the name of the destination directory.

```
cd /src
IMAGES=`find . -type f -name '*.png' -print | egrep '^./[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-.+.png$'`
for IMG in $IMAGES; do
    # optimize here
    DIR=`echo $IMG | sed -E 's/^\.\/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-[0-9]{2}-.+.png/\1\/\2/'`
    mkdir -p /dest/$DIR
    mv /src/$IMG /dest/$DIR/
done
```

Comment: I spend some time with this approach, but I couldn't figure out where the additional `./` in the output came from: `mv ~/Desktop/A/./2013-08-03_test_image.png ~/Desktop/B/uploads/2013/08/`. Although I haven't marked your answer as my solution I'd really like to know.

Comment: The `find` command yields this output. Every line from `find . …` will look like `./some-file`. Hence the `egrep '^./…`.

Comment: To get rid of it, you can pipe an additional `sed -e 's/^.\///'`.

Comment: Ah. Didn't know that it was due to `find`. Using an additional `sed` makes sense. Again. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find `glob` useful and might find some inspiration in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114143/python-module-to-create-music-playlist-windows)

Comment: I spend the last to days (as a Python beginner) with os.split.path. This is a really good link, but I'm kind of thankful to pass (or postpone) the opportunity to learn something new in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another `bash` solution, without using a regex/match:

```
srcdir=<whatever>
destdir=<whatever>

cd "${srcdir}"
for f in *-*-*-*.png
do
  { IFS=- read y m rest
    [[ -d "${destdir}/${y}/${m}" ]] || mkdir -p "${destdir}/${y}/${m}"
    echo mv "${f}" "${destdir}/${y}/${m}/${f}"
  } <<< "${f}"
done
```

The `for f in ...` pattern may need some adjusting, depending on what other stuff you have in your source directory...

Remove the `echo` from in front of `mv` if you're satisfied with the proposed set of commands the above produces (or just pipe the whole thing into a subshell `.... | bash`).

Comment: Skipped some files (especially if there were some hyphen and underscores in the name), so I have to prefer a regex solution. Anyway, a nifty trick and I learned one more thing due to it. Thanks.